# Gravity Form Nested Forms hijack to AirTables

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a form for registering an organization for an event and then a nested form to put who will  sit at the table. A classic example of this: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/
What I need is to push the parent info and nested people into AirTables. I need to manipulate it a before it goes in but I can do that if I could just call the nested data! On submission of the parent form I capture the Unique ID for that submission. In Exporting the child data view Gravity Forms I see that the ID of the parent is appended to the row(s). That is awesome. However, I can't find that variable anywhere when I print_r out a get_entries in GravityForms.
I have been up and down the docs. I am stumped. **How do I call Nested forms results  based on the Parent Entry ID**? I see it on the export but can't find it in the raw data? Below is the raw data from a nested form submission. I see no record of the Parent Entry ID. Yet, when I export it (Excel image) you can see it.

```html
Array ( [id] => 2099 [form_id] => 5 [post_id] => [date_created] => 2022-11-08 16:56:22 [date_updated] => 2022-11-08 16:56:22 [is_starred] => 0 [is_read] => 0 [ip] => 66.248.200.2 [source_url] => https://ecologik.net/ccs-test-form/ [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0 [currency] => USD [payment_status] => [payment_date] => [payment_amount] => [payment_method] => [transaction_id] => [is_fulfilled] => [created_by] => 1 [transaction_type] => [status] => active [1.3] => 1 [1.6] => 1 [3] => 222222 [5] => 2022-11-11 [4.1] => sadfsda [4.3] => sdaf [4.4] => Indiana [4.5] => 45678 [4.6] => United States [2] => https://image.jpeg [is_approved] => 3 [1.2] => [1.4] => [1.8] => [4.2] => [6] => [workflow_current_status_timestamp] => )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the parent id, you can get the array of nested form ids.

```
$entry_id = '1';//replace 1 with the ids of your parent form.  It can either be a specific id or you could run it through a loop and search all the form entries
$entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entry_id );
$get_nested = $entry['3'];//replace 3 with the field id containing your nested form entries.
```

Then you can loop through them to get what you need.

```
if(!empty($get_nested)){
   $nested_ids=explode(",",$get_nested);
   foreach($nested_ids as $nested_id){
      $nested_entry = GFAPI::get_entry( $nested_id );
      //now add code to get what you need from each entry
   }
}
```